# Сбиваются данные при скролинге в GridView на Андроиде

Tags: android, gridview

При старте GridView отображает информацию правильно, но когда начинаю скролить вниз, то вся информация сбивается. Допустим, как видно на первом скрине у меня влазит 2 дня (пн, вт), я скролю вниз, и там начинается среда, но уже с разбросом далее пн, потом вт, а потом вообще каша. Скролю в самый верх, там каша как на скрине втором скрине. Как сделать, чтоб при скролинге не получалось каши?

[image: Информация до скролинга вниз-вверх]
[image: Информация после скролинга вниз-вверх]
Адаптер:

```
    public class ProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    //    private List<DutGroup> products;
    private List<Rozklad> products;

    public ProductAdapter(Context context, List<Rozklad> products) {
        this.context = context;
        this.products = products;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return products.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return products.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView text;
        if (convertView == null) {
            text = new TextView(context);
            String textOut = "";
            textOut = products.get(position).getRozklad();
            text.setText(textOut);
        } else {
            text = (TextView) convertView;
        }
        text.setId(position);

        return text;
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.sky.nestro.e_rozklad.OutRozklad">


    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridV"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="5"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="50dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"></GridView>>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Класс вызова грид:

```
public class OutRozklad extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textView;
    GridView gridView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<String> rozkl = new ArrayList<>();
    String textLes = "";
    Dbase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_out_rozklad);

        db = new Dbase(this);
        List<Rozklad> rozkls=db.getRozk();
        db.close();
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridV);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ProductAdapter(this, rozkls));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ячейки списка переиспользуются при скроле. Т.е. не новая создаётся каждый раз когда появляется ячейка на экране, но старая берётся. А в ней старые данные. Вам надо назначать текст, картинки и прочая каждый раз заново для каждой ячейки при её появлении на экране. Вы же этого не делаете. Т.е. вам надо вот так переписать метод `getView`

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView text;
    if (convertView == null) {
        text = new TextView(context);
    } else {
        text = (TextView) convertView;
    }
    //заново назначаем текст каждый раз при вызове метода
    text.setText(products.get(position).getRozklad());

    text.setId(position);

    return text;
}
```

Comment: Все начало хорошо отображаться, но при скролах вниз-вверх несколько раз, снова начинается каша.